# What is meant by "escape sequence" in the definition of Java string literals?

Tags: java, string, jls

From the Java Language Specification, [Section 3.10.5 String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Characters may be represented by escape sequences - one escape sequence for characters in the range U+0000 to U+FFFF, two escape sequences for the UTF-16 surrogate code units of characters in the range U+010000 to U+10FFFF.

What does this mean? If a character falls within the range U+0000 to U+FFFF, then one escape sequence may be used. How different is one escape sequence from two escape sequences?

By escape sequence, does it refer to `\n`, `\r` and similar? Are these one sequence or two escape sequences?

Comment: You could have simply copied the sentence, instead of retyping it and introducing errors on the way. Also, one of the next sentences says *The escape sequences are described in §3.10.6.*, where it has a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From u+0000 to u+ffff, each number (if you will) represents a characters. However, some unicode characters (called surrogate pairs) are combination of two numbers in the  u+010000 to u+10ffff. So if you have a number  u+010000 to u+10ffff, then a second one is required to represent a valid character.

Answer (score 0):

By escape sequence, they mean stuff like `\u0000` (which you can use in a `String` literal to represent a unicode character).